# Getting rails JSON validation errors in jquery callback

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a create action like so in a rails controller:

```
def create
  @user = User.new(params[:user])
  if @user.save
    redirect_to @user
  else
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render :json => @user.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

And using jQuery's ajax method I have an error callback defined, but can't understand how to get hold of the JSON response – i.e the @user.errors
For a success callback you get a 'data' param passed, but for error you only get (xhr, status, error).

How can I get those json @user.errors in my ajax error callback?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good JavaScript debugging practice: use Firebug to put a breakpoint in your error callback and inspect the function's arguments, drilling down until you find what you need. If your function accepts all 3 arguments, it stands to reason that you should find your `@user.errors` in one of them. Based on my experience, it is probably in `xhr.responseText`, as mkoryak suggested.

Comment: I think I found it in status.responseText

Comment: That's awfully strange. According to the jQuery documentation: 'Possible values for the second argument (besides null) are "timeout", "error", "notmodified" and "parsererror".' So status should just be a string. What you're looking for *should* be somewhere in the xhr object. If it's in your status argument, then something funky is going on. I wonder if your format.json block is somehow incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

here is what i did

```
var onError = function(xhr, status) {
        var error = (status != "timeout") ? xhr.responseText : "";
        //at this point eval error or json.parse it
    };
```